# Does adding the property in existing class in C# Web API impact the angular app UI?

Tags: c#, angular

I have a class in Web API C# called Hero.cs that contains list of properties and a class in angular called Hero.ts with the same properties as in C#. Web API has a method that returns the results as IList.
The angular app is displaying correctly with the values by calling this Web API method. If I add one or more properties in Web API without updating the changes in Hero.ts or anywhere in the angular app, does it impact the angular app UI or creates error?

I have tried adding new property called int age in my web API Hero.cs class without any changes in angular code.

**Existing `hero.ts` class in angular**

```
export class Hero {  id: number;  name: string;}
```

**Existing `hero.cs` class of C# Web API**

```
public class Hero
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**After adding `age` property in `hero.cs` class of C# Web API**

```
public class Hero
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int age { get; set; }
}
```

Expected: No impacts on UI display by adding any number of properties in c# web api class Hero.cs and returning it in one of the method with return type IList of the Hero Class .

Comment: So what's the actual result you are getting after adding? Is it impacting?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I was unable to run angular app as I am just developing Web API. If you have any idea. Thank you!

Comment: Could you please brief more? Unable to run angular app means?

Comment: The angular app is using Web API but I have to return some of the extra columns from the database to be sent to another Web API so I would have to just care about not impacting the angular app. I do have access to angular app or code. @GuruprasadRao :)

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: Correction: Above comment - I do not have access to angular app or code  to run. @PrashantPimpale

Comment: No access to change code on angular app so I cannot update the Hero.ts model class and I do not want to make changes there as well. Thanks!

Comment: From my experience, I feel that it will not impact.. But yea. you need to give a try..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao But I have to make sure if it does not. There is no way that I can run angular app and test it. I guess it does not affect it as well because I am not changing the model class "Hero.ts". If I can be assured, will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding new properties in you C# class will not have impact on your exisiting angular app code in most cases, the response you get from the web api will just have that newly added property. Changing the exisitng properties will have an impact.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your time. Are you sure about it and how to verify? Thanks!

Comment: Well for verification you may need to actually run and test the app, but its quite simple concept
for example; your angular app is displaying user info on the page , then you add "age" property in C# class. Your angular app doesn't know about this new "age" property and there is no code logic in angular app against the new property. The new property will still be in the response of your web api but your angular app will remain the same.

Comment: So the angular app will not throw any error related to not matching property or count of property. For example, number of data exceed or something like that.....

Comment: No, Angular model will map the properties it has an ignore the rest.

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on your UI code. The extra data field `age` will likely be serialized and set to your Angular app, but chances are it'll just be ignored. The only way it would likely make a difference is if you're iterating through the properties of a Hero JavaScript object to find things that aren't defined in the class (or interface).